# explode nested column in pyspark dataframe using spark SQL

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, google-bigquery

I am working on pyspark dataframe. I want to explode the column "event_params". The schema of a nested column "event_params" is:

```
root
 |-- event_timestamp: long (nullable = true)
 |-- event_name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- event_params: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- bag: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- array_element: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- key: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- value: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- string_value: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- int_value: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- float_value: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- double_value: double (nullable = true)
```

I am trying to unnest the column `event_params`. My query is running fine in big query but when I am running the same query is pyspark notebook, I am getting error. I know `unnest` is not supported in pyspark SQL. But not able to find out the query which will return the same output as big query.

Here is my big query SQL:

```sql
    SELECT event_name, event_params,
    (SELECT array_element.value.int_value
       FROM UNNEST(event_params.bag) AS element,
            UNNEST([element.array_element]) AS array_element
       WHERE array_element.key = 'ga_session_id'
         AND array_element.value.int_value IS NOT NULL
       LIMIT 1) ga_session_id
    FROM tbl_name
```

I have tried to run the following queryin pyspark:

```py
    df.createOrReplaceTempView("tbl_name")
    result_df = spark.sql("""
        SELECT
            event_name,
            event_params,
            (SELECT MAX(CAST(array_element.value.int_value AS LONG))
             FROM (
                 SELECT element.array_element
                 FROM temp_tbl
                 LATERAL VIEW explode(event_params.bag) AS element
             ) AS tmp
             LATERAL VIEW explode(tmp.array_element) AS array_element
             WHERE array_element.key = 'ga_session_id' AND array_element.value.int_value IS NOT NULL
             LIMIT 1) AS ga_session_id
        FROM
            tbl_name
""")
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
    An error was encountered:
    cannot resolve 'explode(tmp.array_element)' due to data type mismatch: input to function explode should be array or map type, not struct<key:string,value:struct<string_value:string,int_value:bigint,float_value:double,double_value:double>>; line 11 pos 9;
    'Project [event_name#1, event_params#2, scalar-subquery#3019 [] AS ga_session_id#3020]
    :  +- 'GlobalLimit 1
    :     +- 'LocalLimit 1
    :        +- 'Project [unresolvedalias('MAX(cast('array_element.value.int_value as bigint)), None)]
    :           +- 'Filter (('array_element.key = ga_session_id) AND isnotnull('array_element.value.int_value))
    :              +- 'Generate explode(array_element#3023), false, as, ['array_element]
    :                 +- SubqueryAlias tmp
    :                    +- Project [element#3022.array_element AS array_element#3023]
    :                       +- Generate explode(event_params#3026.bag), false, as, [element#3022]
    :                          +- SubqueryAlias temp_tbl
```

Any help will be highly appreciated. TIA.

Answer (score 0):

Given you have only one array, then you need only one `explode` like this:

```py
# Simulating the input
df = spark.createDataFrame([
    ("event_name", {'bag': [{'element': {'array_element': {'key': 'ga_session_id'}}},\
                {'element': {'array_element': {'key': 'ga_session_id', 'value': 'value2'}}},\
                {'element': {'array_element': {'key': 'key3', 'value': 'value3'}}}]})\
    ], ['event_name', 'event_params'])
df.createOrReplaceTempView("tbl_name")

# Exploding the array and select the needed column from the Struct
result_df = spark.sql("""
    SELECT
        event_name,
        param.element.array_element.value
    FROM
        (SELECT event_name, explode(event_params.bag) AS param FROM tbl_name) t
    WHERE param.element.array_element.value IS NOT NULL
        AND param.element.array_element.key = 'ga_session_id'
    """)

result_df.show(100, False)
```

```
+----------+------+
|event_name|value |
+----------+------+
|event_name|value2|
+----------+------+
```